# How to return ReasonPhrase in response from ActionFilter (.NET Core)

Tags: http, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, action-filter

I am doing the following in a .NET Core MVC ActionFilter to return a Forbidden status code:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new ContentResult()
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,
            Content = "Token header is missing",
            ContentType = "text/plain",
        };
        return;
    }
```

This works fine, but I would like to also set the "ReasonPhrase" which is found in the "HttpResponseMessage" class returned from the calling HttpClient.SendAsync method.  How can I set the ReasonPhrase from an ActionFilter?

Comment: I don’t know anything about action filters, but be aware that reason phrases are a deprecated feature of HTTP — they do not exist in HTTP/2 — so it’s possible that newer APIs may not provide any access to them.

Comment: Also, `application/text` is not a [registered media type](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). You probably want `text/plain`.

Comment: Thanks @VasiliyFaronov!  I didn't know it was deprecated.  I'm just trying to find a way how to convey more info with the status code.  Not the full error message, but something which gives a hint.

Answer (score 0):

on Net 6 this works

> context.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase
> = "Custom reason";